# Maintain ratio of container and children while resize

Tags: css, flexbox, resize, responsive

I have modular grid of cards with and without image, based on flexbox.
Normally cards without image are 50% of the width, cards with image are 100% of the width, and those cards without image that doesn't have a pair are also 100%.

```
----------------
[[ txt ][ img ]] – card with an image
----------------
[  txt ][ txt  ] – 2 cards without image
----------------
[      txt     ] – card without image
----------------
[[ txt ][ img ]] – card with an image
----------------
```

Is it possible to maintain ratio of the cards and its content while resize, and also maintain modularity with css?

**Here's the code**
that let me maintain ratio, but when I try to apply this technique to cards children everything breakes

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-text">
    </div>
    <div class="card-image">  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: wrap
  justify-content: space-between
  width: 620px

.card
  height: 0
  padding-bottom: 50%
  display: flex
  flex-direction: row
  justify-content: space-between
  flex: 1 1 300px

.has-card-image .card-text,
.has-card-image .card-image
  height: 300px
  width: 300px
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: Shure, made an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see one way this could be done w/o script.

Either as in this case, using `px` values, or e.g. using `vw`, and the reason is that the `card-text` and `card-image` needs to know the `wrapper`'s width to be able to size according to the expected output (which mean percent can't be used).

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0x26c2ft/2/)

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 600px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 300px;
}

.card .card-text,
.card .card-image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

.card .card-text:only-child {
  flex: 1 300px;
}

/*  demo styles  */
.card .card-text, .card .card-image {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card .card-text::before {
  content: 'text';
}
.card .card-image::before {
  content: 'image';
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-text">
    </div>
    <div class="card-image">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-text">
    </div>
    <div class="card-image">
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

---

If you need the margin, you'll need an extra wrapper

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0x26c2ft/4/)

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 620px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 300px;
}

.card .card-text,
.card .card-image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.card .card-text:only-child {
  flex: 1 300px;
}


/*  demo styles  */
.card .card-text,
.card .card-image {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card .card-text::before {
  content: 'text';
}

.card .card-image::before {
  content: 'image';
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-text">
      </div>
      <div class="card-image">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-text">
      </div>
      <div class="card-image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Updated*

Here is a version using `vw` and margin, and is responsive.

*Note, the make up for margin set on the wrapper can also be set on each item, though I found it simpler like this.*

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0x26c2ft/7/)

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  width: calc(80vw + 20px);  /*  20px extra for margin  */
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 40vw;
}

.card .card-text,
.card .card-image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 40vw;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.card .card-text:only-child {
  flex: 1 40vw;
}


/*  demo styles  */
.card .card-text,
.card .card-image {
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card .card-text::before {
  content: 'text';
}

.card .card-image::before {
  content: 'image';
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-text">
      </div>
      <div class="card-image">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-text">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-text">
      </div>
      <div class="card-image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! Also I was trying to make its height to grow too on resize. Is it possible somehow with this approach?


I've achieved the content and height growth with the padding technique, but modularity doesn't work how I need, because when the card become fullwidth its ratio changes from 1:1 to 1:2, and padding must be changed from 100% to 50%. Still possible to control the card with class selectors, but  I dropped the idea, and kept all sizes fixed

Comment: @DefaultAccount Would appreciate an accept of my answer if it were useful. When it comes to make the height grow/shrink with the browser, instead of a height set on the items, use a `min-height` on the `inner`: https://jsfiddle.net/0x26c2ft/8/

Comment: Thank you very much for your time